# Create File Group on different drive and move table into it

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I create a File Group on a different drive with MSSQL 2005 and then move a table into it?

Ex: my database is on H:\Product.mdf and H:\Product.ldf

I want to create a new file group on F:\FileGroup\ and then move my table with a clustered index to this new file group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a simple task, and depending on the size of your tables may require a chunk of downtime.

First, you have to define the new file group:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
 add filegroup NewGroup
```

Then, create an appropriate file for that file group, for example:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
 add file
  (
    name = NewFile
   ,filename = 'C:\temp\NewFile.ndf'
   ,size = 100MB
   ,maxsize = unlimited
   ,filegrowth = 100MB
  ) 
 to filegroup NewGroup
```

To move a table onto the file group, you have to create a clustered index for that table on the file group. If you've got a clustered *constraint* (such as a unique or primary key), you'll have to drop it first. Here's one way to move such a table:

```
--  Set up sample table
CREATE TABLE MyTable
 (
   Data varchar(100) not null
   constraint PK_MyTable
    primary key clustered
 )

--  Can't "move" primary key constraint to a new file group
ALTER TABLE MyTable
 drop constraint PK_MyTable

--  This will move the data in the table to the new file group
CREATE clustered index Move_MyTable
 on MyTable (Data)
 on NewGroup

--  Still in the new file group, just no index
DROP INDEX MyTable.Move_MyTable

--  Recreate the primary key, keeping it on the new file group
ALTER TABLE MyTable
 add constraint PK_MyTable
  primary key clustered (Data)
  on NewGroup
```

It is just a bit fussy, so be sure to test everything on copies of your databases first!